Prove $f$ attains its maximizer

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Given $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, define
$$C:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|f(x)\leq f(x_0)\}.$$

Show that $C$ is
closed.

Suppose that $f$ is coercive in the sense that
$$\lim\limits_{||x||\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty.$$ Show that $C$ is
bounded and deduce that $C$ is compact.

Prove that if
$\lim\limits_{||x||\to +\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ then $f$ admits a
maximizer.



For part a), I solved here
For part b), if $C$ is unbounded, then for every $M>0$, there exists $x_M\in C$ s.t $||x_M||>M \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{M\to\infty}f(x_M)=+\infty\Rightarrow$ There exists $M_0$ large enough s.t $f(x_{M_0})>f(x_0)$ (Absurd!)
So $C$ must be bounded. Then according Hein Borel theorem, $C$ is compact. (In the complete metric space $\mathbb{R}^n$, totally bounded is equivalent to bounded)
For part c), if $\lim\limits_{||x||\to +\infty} f(x)=-\infty$, then there exists a sequence $\{x_k\}$ that $||x_k||\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ and $f(x_k)<f(x_0)\Rightarrow x_k\notin C$. I'm stuck here. I don't know how to continue though. Could someone help me to proceed this path or have better ways to approach the rest of this problem? Thanks in advance!

Make a disjunction $f(x) < f(x_0)$ and $f(x) \geq f(x_0)$ for some $x_0$. You can show that $-f$ verifies your previous assumptions so the second case is $x \in C$ for $-f$. Now you can verify that the maximum is attained in $C$

I don't get your point

Take $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, either $f(x) < f(x_0)$ or $x \in {y \mid -f(y) \geq -f(x_0)}$

As $\lim\limits_{||x||\to +\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ there exists some $M>0$ such that if $||x||>M$ then $f(x)<f(0)$.
As $\overline{B(0,M)}$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f$ attains a maximum at some $x_0\in \overline{B(0,M)}$.
This maximum is global, because $f(x)<f(0)\leq f(x_0)$ if $||x||>M$, and $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ if $||x||\leq M$.

simple and easy to understand :)

For c), observe that $-f$ is coercive in the sense of b). In particular, the set
$$C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:-f(x)\leq-f(0)\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x)\geq f(0)\}$$
is compact, and thus $f$ attains a maximum on it at some point $x_M$ as $f$ is continuous. Then this is a global maximum as for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, if $x\in C$, then
$$f(x)\leq\max_{x'\in C}f(x')=f(x_M)$$
and if $x\notin C$ then
$$f(x)<f(0)\leq f(x_M).$$

Very nice and clever to make use of part b) :)
